# How to check if a template exists in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, templates, sinatra

In the Sinatra ruby framework, I have a route like this:

```
get '/portfolio/:item' do
  haml params[:item].to_sym
end
```

This works great if the template that exists (e.g., if I hit `/portfolio/website`, and I have a template called `/views/website.haml`), but if I try a URL that doesn't have a template, like `example.com/portfolio/notemplate`, I get this error:

> Errno::ENOENT at /portfolio/notemplate 
>   No such file or directory - /.../views/notemplate.haml

How can I test and catch whether the template exists?  I can't find an "if template exists" method in the Sinatra documentation.

Comment: See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Looking%20Up%20Template%20Files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there is a Sinatra specific way to do it, but you could always catch the Errno::ENOENT exception, like so:

```
get '/portfolio/:item' do
  begin
    haml params[:item].to_sym
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    haml :default
  end 
end
```

Comment: In theory that's what I'm trying to do, but it gives me the error app.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting kDO or '{' or '(' rescue Errno:ENOENT ^ But I was able to get it working with haml params[:item].to_sym rescue pass Thanks for idea.

Comment: You need to ":". `rescue Errno::ENOENT`

Comment: And the rescue pass doesn't allows you to display an other page. It justs ignores the thing (and ignoring errors is never a good idea).

Comment: dmathieu caught my typo. I've updated the code snippet above. I would be specific about which exception I was catching, since you might mask other sorts of errors with a blanket rescue.

Comment: Good points.  With the typo fix, ry's solution is the better way to handle it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The first answer is not a good one because if a file does not exist a symbol is created anyway. And since symbols are not garbage collected you're easily leaking memory. Just think of a ddos attack against nonexisitng files that create symbols all the time. Instead use this route here (taken from one of my projects routing css files):

```
# sass style sheet generation
get '/css/:file.css' do
  halt 404 unless File.exist?("views/#{params[:file]}.scss")
  time = File.stat("views/#{params[:file]}.scss").ctime
  last_modified(time)
  scss params[:file].intern
end
```